# How deep should I embed with Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Hi I'm new to mongoDB and Mongoid and am little bit confused on when to use embedded documents and how deep to embedd.

So a fictional example:

`Library collection has_many :books, which embeds_many :pages, which embeds_many :sections`

Since I cannot work with say a Section directly I have to go trough books.pages.sections, right?

This would result in this route, `libraries/:id/books/:id/pages/:id/sections/:id`
Which seems a little bit crazy, best practice would be to only nest one level deep, right?
One way would be to have the route `pages/:id/sections/:id` and then stick the bookid in the request?

Would it be harder to query on say, sections? For example if I need to find all the books where sections has tag x?

However if I don't embedd all the way I would have an extra query?

Can someone shed some light? Thanks.

Comment: Routing hasn't explicitly to do with design of your database. You really should avoid such deep nested routes; in most cases they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of I believe that no one can give you the right answer about how deeply you should embed documents. It is highly dependent on your concrete project requirements. In general you should answer some questions to choose appropriate schema design:

1. Will users concurrently update same object in collection? (or what would my boss say if clients lost their updates)
2. Do I need support atomic operations?
3. Do I need to independently show nested collections or are they queried with the parent?
4. Do I need to sort embedded objects?
5. Do I need to query on embedded objects?

If you will answer 1,2-true; 3 I need show them independently (different page); 4,5 - true then i am sure that embedding will be some kind of pain in your ass.

Extra queries should not be a problem I guess.